# How to permanently set an environmental variable in an existing docker container?

Tags: bash, docker

I have an existing docker container and I would like to set an environmental variable in that container.  Can this be done in Docker?  If so, how?

Comment: So you want to add the environment variable to a container you have already run `docker create` or `docker run` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables get set on a process when it starts, and are typically inherited by child processes. In Docker, you can set the environment variable on an image with an `ENV` command in the Dockerfile. And you can configure the default environment used to start the container when you call `docker run -e ...` or define the environment inside your `docker-compose.yml`. So there are quite a few ways to do it before your container is started.

However, once started, there's no way to change it on a running process, and Docker doesn't have a command to alter the default environment of a container that could only effect exec'd processes or a restart of the container if they did add the feature. Therefore, the best option is to stop and remove the existing container, then recreate it with the correct environment.

Comment: Environment can also be set up in an entrypoint or start script, if one exists.